# What is the best way in kotlin to convert an Int value to a Double in a certain format

Tags: kotlin

I have the following numbers:
val first: Int = 531241180
val second: Int = 653345

What would be the best way to write a function which could get first and second as input and return the following values:

output of the fist to a Double value 53.1241180

output of the second to a Double value 6.53345

Comment: Could you please clarify exactly what you mean here? Are you saying you want to *divide* the numbers by 10000000 and 100000 respectively? Or do you want to divide by as much is needed to get a 2-digit number for the first one, and a 1-digit number for the second one, both having the rest as fractional part?

Comment: Indeed! But I want to decide in which position to set the '.' if you see what I mean.
yes 2 digit number and 1 digit number

Comment: I kinda see what you mean but I'm asking for your purpose here. Because the intent of choosing the `.` position seems wrong in itself, so I wonder why you want to do that. Is it about *string* formatting? In this case you don't want a double but a string. Is it about representing a particular *value*? In this case the answer will be about diving by the proper number

Comment: I have latitude and longitudes as int and I want the latitudes to be 2 digits and the rest of them as fractional part

Comment: My solution so far is:

    val lat = calculatePrecision(251020168, 2)
    val lon = calculatePrecision(320261884, 1)
private fun calculatePrecision(coordinate: Int?, min: Int): Double? {
    return coordinate?.let {
        val zeros = "0".repeat(coordinate.toString().length - min)
        coordinate.toDouble() / "1$zeros".toInt()
    }
}

Comment: But this is too hackie

Comment: You probably need to properly define the unit of these integers, then you just have to divide by the corresponding amount to get the correct Double value. Why are you representing those coordinates as ints in the first place?

Comment: I just receive them from some external party

Comment: And what's the definition of those numbers from the external party? Are they given in a fixed unit? Or are they given as "take 2 digits from the left" - that sounds like really poor design if it's the case

Comment: That is something I have to investigate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are allowed to specify, how many numbers you want to see before dot, you can write something like this, avoiding math operations

```
fun intToDouble(value: Int, integerPlaces: Int): Double {
    val raw = value.toString()
    val sb = StringBuilder(raw)

    if(integerPlaces < sb.length()) {
        sb.insert(integerPlaces, ".")
    } else {
        return 0.0 // return 0 if operation is illegal
    }
    
    return sb.toString().toDouble()
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Steyrix! This is a beter version than my solution.

Comment: @Armin you are welcome. You can also improve it by taking care of corner cases, like when arguments for a method are less than zero and etc. Feel free to accept my answer if it helped